# Variable and static text replacements via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the contents of a span with an input value followed by the static text "Items" via jQuery.

Example:
 3 Items

```
 $('#showQty').text($('#selectedQty' + "Items").val());
```

This works but does not include the word "Items" afterwards... Is there any way to do this in JS?

```
$('#showQty').text($('#selectedQty').val());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting `Items` in the jQuery selector. Do this

```
$('#showQty').text($('#selectedQty').val() + " Items");
```

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't worry about the downvotes. It is sort of a simple question though, if you're struggling with this kind of thing in jQuery I'd recommend taking a look at some [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp). Understanding selectors is essential to using jQuery

Comment: If you want to get real fancy (so 1 Item doesn't say "1 Items"): `$('#showQty').text($('#selectedQty').val() + " Item" + ($('#selectedQty').val() == 1 ? "":"s"));` :P